# Tag deletion request: [meanning]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

There's only one question tagged [meanning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meanning), it was probably a typo. Please change it to [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the tag from *meanning* to *meaning*.